# http.exceptionHandler() deprecated and removed in spring 6.2

Tags: spring-boot, https

I am trying to set up HttpSecurity in Spring 6.1.2 and I need to add jwtEntrypoint to it but I discovered

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.cors().and().csrf().disable();
    http.exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint);has been removed
```

I tried http.exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint); as seen in some answers but it still doesnt work

Answer (score 10):

I found the solution. Apparently spring has removed http.exceptionHandling() in spring 6.1 so to solve the problem I did

```
  http.exceptionHandling((exception)-> exception.authenticationEntryPoint(jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint).accessDeniedPage("/error/accedd-denied"));
```

Comment: Thanks @Obj (+1). Its absolutely bananas to me that the Spring Security team hasn't attempted to explain this in any public facing docs and that I have to go to SO for the authoritative answer!